# Returning by const value and assigning to a non const variable compiles

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, return-value, auto

I don't understand why the following code is allowed to use the non const version of foo. I would like to forbid a const Array variable to provide a non const ArrayView.

```
#include <iostream>

struct ArrayView
{
    ArrayView() = default;
    ArrayView(const ArrayView&) = delete;
    ArrayView(ArrayView&&) = delete;

    void foo() {std::cout << "non const" << std::endl;}
    void foo() const {std::cout << "const" << std::endl;}
};

struct Array
{
    const ArrayView createView() const
    {
        return {};
    }
};

int main()
{
    const Array arr{};
    auto view = arr.createView();
    view.foo();

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
non const
```

I have gcc 10.1.0 on windows 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule of type deduction for `auto` is same as template argument deduction; `view` is declared as non-reference and the `const` part of the return value of `createView` is ignored. As the result the type of `view` is `ArrayView`, not `const ArrayView`.

On the other hand, if you call `foo` on the return value directly, the `const` version would be selected. e.g.

```
arr.createView().foo();
```

As the workaround you can declare `view` as `const` explicitly,

```
const auto view = arr.createView();
```

Or declare `view` as reference.

```
auto& view = arr.createView(); // the type of view is const ArrayView&
```

---

PS: I noticed that you marked both the copy/move constructor of `ArrayView` as `delete`. Since C++17 in `auto view = arr.createView();` they'll be elided completely because of [mandatory copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision). It doesn't matter here whether they're usable or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why is the const part of the return value ignored by value and not by reference ?

Comment: @Cevik `view` doesn't have to be `const`. For example, given `const int i1 = 42;`, then `int i2 = i1;` is quite fine. `i2` doesn't have to be `const` just because `i1` is; `i2` is an independent object which is copied from `i1`. So if you want it to be `const` you have to specify explicitly. For reference, then it must be `const`. e.g. it must be `const int& i2 = i1;`, `int& i2 = i1;` is invalid.

Comment: That's interesting. I thinked it would be true only for POD types that doesn't have explicit copy constructors, but I deleted them in ArrayView for this purpose. It seems that a "copy in spirit" is made to remove the constness, without my agreement.

Comment: @Cevik The rule stays same here, for non-class types and class types.

Comment: Thank you, I think i will introduce a IsConst template argument to ensure it whatever the client does with auto. I cannot produce a left value reference in my real code ;)